# Which tools for micro-benchmarking?

Tags: benchmark, perf, profiling

I'm not sure which tool to use for micro-benchmarking a C program.

I would like to measure both:

- Memory usage, RSS ( Resident Set Size )
- CPU cycles

I did use `perf record -g` and `perf script` piped into an awk script. This worked for finding the memory usage, but CPU cycles weren't accurate because `perf record` gets the cpu cycles by sampling. `perf stat` is accurate but obviously doesn't give per-function stats. The perf_event library seems to be terribly documented and a meal of a task for simple benchmarking.

Having briefly looked at:

- SystemTap
- DTrace
- LTTng
- gperftools
- likwid
- PAPI

Which seem like decent, well-documented tools.

What would you recommend looking the most into? Or any other suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your own C code, so you can just call [getrusage()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)  to obtain the statistics that you mentioned.
Call it before and after the benchmarked code of interest.

Syscalls have overhead.
You possibly wish for the benchmarked code to loop through several iterations for a single measurement.
If multiple runs of same code produce highly variable timings, then your loop counter is set too low.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802519/22863450) answer seems to suggest that getrusage output is not so accurate. For micro-benchmarking I really need cycle count that is correct for the process, irrespective of context switching and cpu frequency scaling.

Comment: That answer is a decade old, and appears to be describing kernels that were old even at that time. In a modern tickless kernel, you should not observe such artifacts. In any event, you are free to use other time bases to measure elapsed time. I mentioned getrusage so that you could observe the resident set size.

Comment: Adding to what @J_H wrote that whatever the clock source, its accuracy is likely to be négligeable when compared to the stdev of your benchmark.

Comment: Thank you getrusage looks great for a simple way to get current rss. Perf can set tracepoints on rss update events so the metric has more granularity.

Comment: @MC68020 Who's to say the benchmark would have any deviation in cycles? And negligible difference is subjective.